# Putting strings from multiple double pointer array to a single pointer array

Tags: arrays, c

I am using a function called generateSentence which takes in 5 double-pointer arrays full with strings from a text file. It also takes in 5 integers with the size of those arrays. What I am trying to do is a random number generator that picks a word from those double-pointer arrays and then I need to combine the 8 words I would get from the other arrays into a single one. I have tried a few things and I think I am thinking about this logically wrong so some help would be nice.

```
char* generateSentence(char ** noun, char ** verb, char ** adjective, char ** preposition, char ** article, int nounsize, int verbsize, int adjsize, int prepositionsize, int articlesize){

    int xnoun = rand()% nounsize;
    int xverb = rand()% verbsize;
    int xadj = rand()% adjsize;
    int xprep = rand()% prepositionsize;
    int xarticle = rand()% articlesize;
```

Also the array won't be bigger than 100 characters so I tried allocating memory here

```
    char *sentence = malloc(100 * sizeof *sentence);
    
    
    
    memcpy(sentence , article[xarticle], strlen(**article[xarticle]));
    
    /*
    strcpy(sentence , adjective[xadj]);
    strcpy(sentence , noun[xnoun]);
    strcpy(sentence , verb[xverb]);
    strcpy(sentence , preposition[xprep]);
    strcpy(sentence , article[xarticle]);
    strcpy(sentence , adjective[xadj]);
    strcpy(sentence , noun[xnoun]);
    
    */
    
    /*
    if(sentence){
        *sentence[0] = ("%s",**article[xarticle]);
        *sentence[1] = ("%s",**adjective[xadj]);
        *sentence[2] = ("%s",**noun[xnoun]);
        *sentence[3] = ("%s",**verb[xverb]);
        *sentence[4] = ("%s",**preposition[xprep]);
        *sentence[5] = ("%s",**article[xarticle]);
        *sentence[6] = ("%s",**adjective[xadj]);
        *sentence[7] = ("%s",**noun[xnoun]);
    
    }  */


    return sentence;
}
```

Comment: After the malloc: 
`sentence[0] = '\0'; //start it off empty` then
`strcat(sentence, article[xarticle]); strcat(sentence,adjective[xadj]);` ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf()` to combine all the words.

```
sprintf(sentence, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", article[xarticle], adjective[xadj], noun[xnoun], verb[xverb], preposition[xprep], article[xarticle], adjective[xadj], noun[xnoun]);
```